# DHCP offer is unicast but DHCPACK is broadcast

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

My DHCP server broadcast `DHCPACK 0xffffffff` . it is not working on `layer 3 dhcp relay agent` . as it can not forward this broadcast message to my client. can any one help me from exactly the broadcast bit set ? should I send any parameter to dhcp server so It will send `DHCPACK as a unicast` but not broadcast ?

Comment: Are you sure that your DHCP relay is well configured ?

Comment: Same thought here. I believe the problem is not the DHCP server, but the DHCP relay agent.

Comment: some minor check in dhcp code,and it works fine , I have checked if "giaddr" field in present packet,it should unicast. is there any side effect of it ? will it work on layer 2, layer 3 both devices ?